# Discord Bot and Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord

Hi I need some help with my discord bot. I searched up the errors and tried to fix it, but it just doesn’t work. It could have been a coding error on my end. PLEASE HELP and Thanks!
Link for the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/Verggz/Electrolite

Edit: errors that keep occuring
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

```
2022-01-23T15:14:15.475287+00:00 app[worker.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476783+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/main.ts:1
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476784+00:00 app[worker.1]: import express from 'express';
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476785+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^^^^^^
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476785+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476785+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476786+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476786+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476786+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476787+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476787+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476787+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2022-01-23T15:14:15.476788+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electrolite",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "literally just project scyll v2 but better",
  "main": "./build/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=512 ./build/main.js && export NODE_ENV=production",
    "dev": "tsc && node ./build/main.js",
    "bot": "node ./build/bot/main.bot.js",
    "botdev": "tsc && node ./build/bot/main.bot.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "minecraft"
  ],
  "author": "PenguinDetox",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.11.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.2.0-canary.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.26.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "hypixel-api-reborn": "^9.0.3",
    "prismarine-nbt": "^2.0.0",
    "set-interval-async": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.4",
    "@types/set-interval-async": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
worker: node main.ts
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577).

Comment: "I searched up the errors"—please [edit] your question to include the exact error messages and relevant code snippets. And please be more specific than "just doesn’t work". We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code on GitHub, _especially_ without having any idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: Hello Chris, I have added the error to the original post. Sorry for not adding the error before.

Comment: It looks like you aren't running a production build. Please add the `scripts` section of your `package.json` and, if you have one, the contents of your `Procfile`.

Comment: How do I add it to the Procfile?

Comment: I didn't ask you to modify your `Procfile`. We have no idea what it contains now. I asked you to _show us_ your `package.json` and `Procfile`. Please [edit] your question and add that information.

Comment: My bad, I’m very new to this site. But I have added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do here, but the main issue at the moment is that you're asking Heroku to run your *TypeScript* code, not the compiled JavaScript. This is being done via your `Procfile`:

```
worker: node main.ts
```

You have a completely different command in your `package.json`:

```
"start": "node --max-old-space-size=512 ./build/main.js && export NODE_ENV=production",
```

This is probably closer to what you want, but we can't just use it like this.

The `&& export NODE_ENV` part is unlikely to do anything useful: it will wait until your code stops running, then export an environment variable, then exit. Let's remove it:

```
"start": "node --max-old-space-size=512 ./build/main.js",
```

Now the issue is that `build/main.js` doesn't exist. You need to tell Heroku to build it during deployment. Based on your `dev` script, I believe that just involves running `tsc`.

Let's add a build script to do that:

```
"build": "tsc",
"start": "node --max-old-space-size=512 ./build/main.js",
```

(I don't see `typescript` in your `devDependencies`, which means `tsc` might fail to run. Make sure to include all dependencies in your `package.json`.)

Okay, so your `build` script will now tell Heroku to build your application during deployment and your `build/main.js` should exist. Your `start` script has been updated.

Let's deal with your `Procfile`. Update it to match the new `start` script:

```
worker: node --max-old-space-size=512 ./build/main.js
```

Commit all those changes and redeploy.